# jQuery - check if an input is not a select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

How can I find out if an input field is anything other than a `select` ?

I tried with `if($(el).not("select"))` and I get the selects too...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
if(!$(el).is("select")) {
    // the input field is not a select
}
```

Comment: Why didn't the original work out of interest? It looks like it should at a glance... Your answer just seems to be moving around the negation a bit... I see the answer in other people's answers. Possibly a good idea to edit it into this one since this is the accepted answer so should really be the only one people need to look at (IMHO). :)

Comment: @Chris, because the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function returns an array of jquery elements, not boolean value you can test for true/false.

Answer (score 3):

`$(el).not("select")` gives you array. Array is always gives **true** in boolean expressions. But after you apply not, this array of elements won't contain selects. See working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VDHDt/).

Comment: but I only need a true/false value, not a array. How can I get that?

Answer (score 3):

The `.not()` method returns a new jQuery object with everything from the original object that doesn't match the selector.
You can't just use it in an `if` statement like that.

Instead, you use the `.is` method, which checks whether the element matches a selector and returns a boolean.

```
if (!$(el).is('select'))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about giving the `<select>` tags a class:

```
$(el + ":not('.select')")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(el).selectedIndex)
```

If it has a SelectedIndex property, it's a `<SELECT>`

Comment: For firefox this was counting as false if nothing was selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(el)[0].nodeName != 'select')
```